# TFS build is not showing test result summary

Tags: asp.net-core, tfs, continuous-integration, visual-studio-2019

I am running a CI build on TFS server using Visual Studio 2019. My project is based on .NET Core. The test results are not getting published after running the build.

[image: Here is the image showing the Tests Results]

Comment: Are you running the test task in your build? If you are, what type of test are they, MSTest, NUnit, XUnit? Have you ticked the publish result in the test task? If not MSTests, you will need to use the Publish Test result task and point to your tests output.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to check your pipeline if that contain corresponding tasks.

You could choose to use [Visual Studio Test task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/vstest?view=azure-devops) in your build definition/pipeline.

Use this task in a build or release pipeline to run unit and functional tests (Selenium, Appium, Coded UI test, and more) using the Visual Studio Test Runner. Other than MSTest-based tests, test frameworks that have a Visual Studio test adapter, such as xUnit, NUnit, Chutzpah, can also be executed.

Tests that target the **.NET core framework** can be executed by specifying the appropriate target framework value.

Another choice is using [.NET Core CLI task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops) with test command, and you need to combine with [Publish Test Results task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to show the results in the build summary.

If you already have the right configuration. Then check the logs of test related task. For example ,if it does not generate the test results, there should also no test result to publish. Also set `system.debug=true` to enable verbose debug mode to get a more detail result.

Besides, also attach an official doc show [Build, test, and deploy .NET Core apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/dotnet-core?view=azure-devops) in case you need.